# gxt (extJS) Combobox throws unresponsive JS error in IE -8

Tags: extjs, combobox, gxt

I have a gxt combobox which has a large data store(350 objects) assigned. When I try to display the list by clicking the drop down icon, I get unresponsive js error in IE- 8. I know its trying to populate around 350 objects(lists) and its taking its time. If I ignore the error few times, it will eventually load. Is there a  workaround to avoid the js error other than cutting down the data store? I found some articles where some users suggest suspending/resuming layouts when loading data.But I am not quite sure how to do it.I am just setting the store and not touching it there after, so where do i suspend/resume layout?Should I modify the combobox class or something? I am using GXT 2.2.4
This is my code.

`private ComboBox hierarchyName;`
`private ListStore<BeanModel> listStoreHierarchyName`
`hierarchyName.setStore(listStoreHierarchyName);`--- has 350 objects

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?226443-IE8-quot-Unresponsive-Script-quot-Prompt
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?205909-IE-quot-Stop-running-this-script-quot-when-loading-large-store

Comment: it is really difficult for users to select from 350 items ... perhaps a better approach would be to have a type-ahead field that narrows down the query on the server side and bring back a smaller set. another idea would be to paginate results in the dropdown - there is an example of this on the sencha website.

Comment: @dbrin - thanks for the suggestions, I already have typeAhead set to true. Didn't knew pagination could be implemented for drop downs. Need to look at it. Thanks again.

Comment: yes, take a look at this example: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/extjs-build/examples/form/forum-search.html

Comment: @dbrin- i did look at pagination, but the problem is I need an option to populate the list by default even without any user input.I heard I can substitute combo box by listView which displays the entire list by default.But will that avoid the js error?

Comment: Ok, issue is fixed. I implemented pagination in combo box and now it retrieves only 100 rows per page.Also there is query support.